# All Roots to be on unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $p(z)=1+a(z+z^2+\cdots+z^{n-1})+z^n, a\in{\bf R}, n\geq 2.$ Then  the necessary and sufficient conditions for $p(z)$ to have all its roots on the unit circle are $-2/(n-1)\le a\le2n/(n-1)$ for odd $n$ and $-2/(n-1)\le a\le2$ for even $n$.

Comment: I checked that $-2\leq a \leq 2$ for $n=2$ by a simple calculation, and $-1\leq a \leq 3$ for $n=3$ since $1+a(z+z^2)+z^3 = (1+z)(1+(a-1)z+z^2)$. For an odd $n$, $1+a(z+\ldots+z^{n-1})+z^n = (1+z)(1+(a-1)z+z^2+(a-1)z^3+\ldots+z^{n-1})$. I roughly guess that $p(z)$ have all its roots on the unit circle iff its all solution are $-1$ or complex numbers. (I think that we can prove one direction easily, but I didn't yet.) I think this problem is very interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since
$$\begin{align}p(z)&=1+z^n+a\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}z^k=1+z^n+a\left(\frac{z^n-z}{z-1}\right)\\
&=z^{n/2}\left(z^{n/2}+z^{-n/2}\right)+a\left(\frac{z^{(n+1)/2}\left(z^{(n-1)/2}-z^{(1-n)/2}\right)}{z^{1/2}\left(z^{1/2}-z^{-1/2}\right)}\right)\\
&=z^{n/2}\left(2\cos\left(\frac n2\theta\right)+a\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12\theta\right)}\right)\right)=0\end{align}$$
Where $z=e^{i\theta}$ lies on the unit circle. We have
$$a=-\frac{2\cos\left(\frac n2\theta\right)\sin\left(\frac12\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)-\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}=1-\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}$$
We need to have that ratio take on the same value $n$ times. Let's plot it for odd and even $n$:

```
% Circle.m

n = input('Enter a positive integer:> ');
npts = 500;
theta1 = linspace(0,pi,npts+2);
theta = theta1(2:end-1);
num = sin((n+1)/2*theta);
den = sin((n-1)/2*theta);
for k = 2:length(den),
    if den(k)*den(k-1) <= 0,
        den(k-1) = NaN;
    end
end
plot(theta,num./den);
ylabel(['$\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n' ...
    '+1}2\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{n' ...
    '-1}2\theta\right)}$'],'Interpreter','latex');
xlabel('\theta');
title(['Critical function for n = ' num2str(n)]);
axis([0 pi -2 2]);
tol = 0.01;
a = -2/(n-1)+tol;
P = [1 a*ones(1,n-1) 1];
roots(P)
abs(roots(P))-1
if mod(n,2) == 0,
    a = 2-tol;
else
    a = 2*n/(n-1)-tol;
end
P = [1 a*ones(1,n-1) 1];
roots(P)
abs(roots(P))-1
```

[image: fig 7]
[image: fig 8]
In both cases
$$\lim_{\theta\rightarrow0^+}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}=\frac{n+1}{n-1}$$
For odd $n$,
$$\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\pi^-}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}=\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\pi^-}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}=-\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)$$
For even $n$,
$$\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\pi^-}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}=-1$$
So for odd $n$ we get $\frac{n-1}2$ roots for $\theta\in(0,\pi)$ and their additive inverses and one for $\theta=\pi$ when $z=-1$ for a total of $n$ roots, provided
$$-\frac2{n-1}<a<\frac{2n}{n-1}$$
For even $n$ we get $\frac n2$ roots for $\theta\in(0,\pi)$ and their additive inverses for a total of $n$ roots, provided
$$-\frac2{n-1}<a<2$$
As for what happens at the endpoints of these intervals, it's getting too late here to work that out. Maybe tomorrow.

**EDIT**: I'm back and the first order of business is to prove that
$$f(\theta)=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}$$
Is a decreasing function of $\theta$.
$$\begin{align}f^{\prime}(\theta)&=\frac{\frac{n+1}2\cos\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)\sin\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)-\frac{n-1}2\sin\left(\frac{n+1}2\theta\right)\cos\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}{\sin^2\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}\\
&=\frac{\frac12\sin n\theta-\frac n2\sin\theta}{\sin^2\left(\frac{n-1}2\theta\right)}\end{align}$$
So that relies on us proving that the numerator $g(\theta)=\frac12\left(\sin n\theta-n\sin\theta\right)<0$ for $\theta\in(0,\pi)$. $g(0)=0$ and $g^{\prime}(\theta)=\frac n2\left(\cos n\theta-\cos\theta\right)<0$ for $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2n}$ because $\cos\theta$ takes $n$ times as long to decrease to any given positive value as $\cos n\theta$ does. A function that starts out at zero and has a negative first derivative is inherently negative for positive values of its argument. At $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2n}$ this means that already $n\sin\theta>1$. At the other end of the interval, for odd $n$ $\sin n(\pi-\theta)=\sin n\theta$ just as $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin\theta$ so $g(\pi-\theta)=g(\theta)$ which means that our analysis that showed $g(\theta)<0$ for $0<\theta\le\frac{\pi}2$ also shows $g(\theta)<0$ for $\frac{\pi}2<\theta<\pi$. For even $n$, $\sin n(\pi-\theta)=-\sin\theta$ so clearly $g(\theta)<0$ for $\pi-\frac{\pi}{2n}le\theta<\pi$ so for $\frac{\pi}2<\theta<\pi-\frac{\pi}{2n}$ recall the $n\sin\theta>1$ so in this case as well $g(\theta)<0$ for $\frac{pi}2<\theta<\pi$.

Having proved that $f^{\prime}(\theta)$ is decreasing we observe that the zeros of its denominator happen when $\theta=\frac{2\pi k}{n-1}$ for integer $k$. For $0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}2$ this implies that $0\le k\le\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\rfloor$. For odd $k$ this happens for $k=0$, $k=(n-1)/2$, and for $(n-3)/2$ points in between for a total of $(n-1)/2$ intervals where $f(\theta$ is continuous and decreasing. So for real there can be $2(n-1)/2$ solutions to $f(\theta)=1-a$ counting both positive and negative values of $\theta$ not to mention that $p(-1)=0$ for odd $n$, so that's all $n$ zeros of $p(z)$. For even $n$, $k=0$, $k=(n-2)/2$, and for $(n-4)/2$ points in between for $(n-2)/2$ intervals but also the interval $\pi-\frac{\pi}{n-1}<\theta<\pi$ where $f(\theta)$ is continuous and decreasing. Thus there can be $2n/2=n$ solutions to $f(\theta)=1-a$ in this case as well.

A lot of hard work to prove what we could see just by looking at the pictures -- shows that a picture is worth a thousand equations. But now on to the endpoints. At the left endpoint if $a=-2/(n-1)$, then
$$p(1)=2-\frac2{n-1}(n-1)=0$$
and
$$p^{\prime}(1)=n-\frac2{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=n-\frac2{n-1}\cdot\frac12n(n-1)=0$$
So we do indeed get a double root at $z=1$ and so still $n$ roots, though not all distinct, when $a=-2/(n-1)$. At the right endpoint for even $n$, when $a=2$
$$p(-1)=2+2\left(\frac{(-1)^n-(-1)}{(-1)-1}\right)=2-2=0$$
And
$$p^{\prime}(z)=nz^{n-1}+2\frac{(n-1)z^n-nz^{n-1}+1}{(z-1)^2}$$
So $p^{\prime}(-1)=-n+2\frac{2n}4=0$ so again a double root at $z=-1$. For odd $n$,
$$p(-1)=0+\frac{2n}{n-1}\frac{(-1)^n-(-1)}{(-1)-1}=0$$
And $p^{\prime}(-1)=n+\frac{2n}{n-1}\frac{2(1-n)}4=0$ and
$$p^{\prime\prime}(z)=n(n-1)z^{n-2}+\frac{2n}{n-1}\frac{(n-2)(n-1)z^n-2n(n-2)z^{n-1}+n(n-1)z^{n-2}-2}{(z-1)^3}$$
So $p^{\prime\prime}(-1)=-n(n-1)+\frac{2n}{n-1}\frac{-4(n-1)^2}{(-8)}=0$ for a triple root at $z=-1$ In both cases, then, all $n$ roots lie on the unit circle even though not all distinct.

Thus the condition that all roots lie on the unit circle is $-2/(n-1)\le a\le2n/(n-1)$ for odd $n$ and $-2/(n-1)\le a\le2$ for even $n$. If $n=1$ there is always only one root $z=-1$ so all roots lie on the unit circle for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ in that case.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a brilliant,  detailed answer. I am curious to know for what values of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma $ of the polynomial $q(z)=\alpha+\beta(z+z^2+\cdots+z^{n-1})+\gamma z^n,$  the sum $p(z)+q(z)$ has no zeros inside the unit disc? or all zeros in the closed unit disc? Any intuitive suggestion?

Comment: This approach isn't going to work very well with that kind of problem I think. The kind of problem you are proposing reminds me of what one might see in an electrical engineering control systems text. Have you tried root locus techniques to see if that would answer some of your questions?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try on that.